# using websphere MQ 7.5.0 on 2 different virtual machines

Tags: ibm-mq

i am currently experimenting on websphere MQ 7.5.0, which is used to send message from one machine to another.

I have a server with 2 virtual machines (VM1 and VM2) configured, as well as another standalone laptop. all the machines mentioned above are set using the same ip range (192.168.0.2 -5) and the same subnet, and i turn off the firewall during my experiment.

I follow the ibm website and set up the necessary queue manager, local queues, remote definition and channels. I have success with connecting the laptop to the server, and also from the server to VM1.

however, when i am trying to connect VM1 and VM2 together, after binding, my sender channel is still in retrying status, it means that connection between VM1 and VM2 is not established. I try to ping VM2 using my cmd and i receive all the packets successfully.

what could be the reasons why VM1 and VM2 cannot be connected? Is there any requirement for IBM MQ such that at least one of the MQ must be located in the physical computer?

Thank you everybody in advance!

Comment: No mention here of having created and started a listener, nor of the error log entries in both QMgrs. Please consider clicking on the [tag:websphere-mq] tag and reading the guidance on what information is needed to help diagnose and then update your question with additional info. Make sure to edit the question rather than adding a comment or answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the ports that are being used by you VM queue managers and be sure the listeners for those ports are running successfully and not being used by another process.